# Why we can't change FetchRequest at NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

Example I have NSFetchedResultsController called at ListController called FetchController

```
+(NSFetchRequest * )fetchRequestInContext: (NSString*) entityName : (NSPredicate *) predicate : (NSString*) sortKey : (BOOL) sortAscending;

+(NSFetchedResultsController *) searchControllerInContext: (NSString*) entityName : (NSPredicate *) predicate : (NSString*) sortKey : (BOOL) sortAscending 
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [self fetchRequestInContext:entityName :predicate :sortKey :sortAscending];

    NSFetchedResultsController * FRC=[[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:[ThreadClass managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:Nil cacheName:Nil]autorelease];
    NSLog(@"FRC : %@",FRC);
    return FRC;
}
```

look at that code, I call searchControllerInContext when I want to make NSFetchedResultsController and then perfom it with this code :

```
if (![[self ListController].FetchController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

the problem is I dont like to always performFetch when request is change, I want to make it easy with

```
[self ListController].FetchController.fetchRequest=[self FunctionTogetNewRequest];
```

but the [self ListController].FetchController.fetchRequest is readonly..

I want do this because I Don't want to perfomFetch again and again.. can I do that?

I mean, if I have a program that give records based on what user put in search box, should I create a new controller every time the search box content change? That would be strange. I thought the whole point of using NSFetchedResultsController is so we don't have to do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Even though `fetchRequest` is a readonly property, you can modify it. For example, setting the predicate of the fetch request works perfectly well as long as you're not caching the results (or as long as you delete the cache first). I've used this technique successfully in a number of projects. After modifying the fetch request, you should call `performFetch` again.

Bottom line: you don't need to create a FRC every time the search terms change. Just delete your cache, change the fetch request's predicate and fetch the new result set with your existing instance.

Comment: What will happen if I cache the result? Do I need to call performFetch again if I do not cache the result?

Comment: Modifying the fetch request will make your cached results invalid. Any time you modify the fetch request, you should re-fetch your result set.

Comment: While this may work, please consider what Apple writes in its documentation: `IMPORTANT
You must not modify fetchRequest after invoking this method [NSFetchedResultsController init method]. For example, you must not change its predicate or the sort orderings.`

Comment: They've since updated their documentation to say it is okay if the cache is set to be nil. But of course if you delete it each time it should be okay :)

Answer (score 11):

> if I have a program that give records based on what user put in
>   search box, should I create a new controller every time the search box
>   content change?

Yes, because you change the predicate on a the fetch which requires generating a new controller.

> I thought the whole point of using NSFetchedResultsController is so we
>   don't have to do that?

The point of an FRC is to automatically handle the interaction between the context and the tableview. It has dedicated properties to return sections and rows as well as delegate methods to modify the table in response to changes in the data model. Since an FRC is defined by the its fetch, when you make a change to the fetch, you need to generate a new FRC

Don't make the mistake of thinking of an FRC has a big, expensive object. It's not. There is not a problem with creating and disposing of a large number of FRC as needed.